# Oracle SQL, trying to get one value from a select/join to use to update one column in one table?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, dml

I have one table with the following columns:

```
T_RESOLVED_DATE
I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER
I_RESOLVED_SET_NUMBER
I_STATION_CODE
I_RESOLVED_START_MIN
I_DURATION
I_PERSON_NUMBER
I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID
```

Initially, I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID is set to null.
Then I have another table with the following columns:

```
T_RESOLVED_DATE
I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER
I_PERSON_NUMBER
I_AGE
T_GENDER
I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID
```

I am trying to update I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID in the first table by using the value of I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID in the second table where the T_RESOLVED_DATE, I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER, and I_PERSON_NUMBER are equal in both tables.  The first table may contain multiple rows with the same DATE, HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER, and PERSON_NUMBER, because the rows can vary by the rest of the columns.

I have tried to do a select and a group by which seems to get me part way there, but I am getting a "single-row subquery returns more than one row" error when I try to update the columns in the first table.  This is what I've tried, along with variations of it:

```
UPDATE
  Table1
SET
    I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID =
(SELECT
    b.I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID
FROM Table1 a,
     Table2 b
WHERE a.I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER = b.I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER AND
      a.I_PERSON_NUMBER = b.I_PERSON_NUMBER AND
      a.T_RESOLVED_DATE = b.T_RESOLVED_DATE
GROUP BY b.I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The multiple lines lines returned for the same `DATE, HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER, and PERSON_NUMBER` will always bring the same `I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID` ? If it yes just add to your sub-query `and rownum = 1`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thank you.  The problem with this is the sub-query returns for example 3 rows if there are 3 different COVIEW_DEMO_ID's in each table.  When I add in the rownum = 1 to the subquery, then I am just updating the column with the value from the first row.  What I need is to update the column with the appropriate value of the 3 returned in the subquery I believe.

Comment: That's why I asked. Oracle can't do the update because it won't know which registry to use to update table1 from the 3 results of the table2 that cames because of the join operation. So I think a little PLSQL block would be the best fit to your problem. And Another question, is it possible that you have more than one registry for `DATE, HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER, and PERSON_NUMBER` on table2? Because if it is, you have a problem, you would have to find another field to make the unicity

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thank you.  No it is not possible that there is more than one record for one DATE, HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER, and PERSON_NUMBER in table 2.  It is possible to have more than one date with the same household and person number.  Thank you for your input.  I will look in to PLSQL.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work using this statement:

```
MERGE INTO table1 a
USING
(
   SELECT DISTINCT
      T_RESOLVED_DATE,
      I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER,
      I_PERSON_NUMBER,
      I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID
    FROM
      table2
) b
ON
(
  a.T_RESOLVED_DATE = b.T_RESOLVED_DATE
  AND a.I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER = b.I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER
  AND a.I_PERSON_NUMBER = b.I_PERSON_NUMBER
) WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET
  a.I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID = b.I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per our discussion on the comments this would be a simple PLSQL block to do what you need. I'm doing direct from my head without test, so you may need to fix some sintaxe mistake.

```
BEGIN

    FOR rs IN ( SELECT I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER,
                       I_PERSON_NUMBER,
                       I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID,
                       T_RESOLVED_DATE
                FROM Table2 ) LOOP

        UPDATE Table1
           SET I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID = rs.I_COVIEW_DEMO_ID
         WHERE I_PERSON_NUMBER = rs.I_PERSON_NUMBER
           AND I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER = rs.I_HOUSEHOLD_NUMBER
           AND T_RESOLVED_DATE = rs.T_RESOLVED_DATE;

    END LOOP;
    --commit after all updates, if there is many rows you should consider in
    --making commits by blocks. Define a count and increment it whithin the for
    --after some number of updates you commit and restart the counter
    COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  Please see my answer if you are curious about how I got it to work.

Comment: @Lani1234 Great solution +1 for you on that.

Comment: I give all the credit to my co-worker but I agree, great solution.